# How to remove a particular string from htaccess redirect if it exists?

Tags: string, .htaccess, url-rewriting, redirect

I have the following htaccess code:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} .*jpg$|.*gif$|.*png$ [NC] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !mysitee\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ([^/]*)\.(jpg|gif|png)$ http://mysitee.com/?attachment=$1 [NC]
```

What this does is change:

```
http://mysitee.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/my-image.jpg
```

to this:

```
http://mysitee.com/?attachment=my-image
```

---

The code works very well, but sometimes the following url occurs:

```
http://mysitee.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/my-image-750x500.jpg
```

which results in

```
http://mysitee.com/?attachment=my-image-750x500
```

but I want it to remove "-750x500" to never display that in the rewritten url.

Please help thank you

Comment: What are the possible parameters? Only `700x500` or can be any numbers? And in the original URL you have `700-500` - is that a typo?

Comment: it could be numbers and  letters, the point is I want to be able to specifically remove anything I specifically define like for example `-750x500` from within the url in this code. In this example, it will be numbers and letters, and you can't just strip the numbers because those numbers may also be contained elsewhere in the filename like for example `my7-image0x-321x987.jpg` in which I would want to extract and remove `-321x987` from the filename.